# Reading a String array [NETWORKING]

Tags: java, sockets, networking, inputstream

I have this block of code to read an array sent from the server to the client of recent updates, the issue is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It will print out the version properly, but everything else will either not print out, all print out on the same line, or have 2 on the same line.

The purpose of this is to receive a String[] of recent updates from the server, which is looped through and sent as an individual String. Those updates are then displayed on a GUI.

```
private Response update() {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(RS2Client.IP, 55555);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        socket.getInputStream().read(bytes);
        String version = new String(bytes);
        System.err.println("VERSION READ " + version);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            socket.getInputStream().read(b);
            String text = new String(b);
            getRecentUpdates().add(text.trim());
            System.out.println("New update: " + text);
        }
        for (String update : getRecentUpdates()) {
            System.err.println(update);
        }
        System.out.println("Client connected! Version: " + version);
        socket.close();
        if (Double.parseDouble(version) != RS2Client.CLIENT_VERSION) {
            return Response.BAD;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.ERROR;
    }
    return Response.GOOD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A socket sends a stream of bytes. It does not keep track of the end of each byte array you send.

If you want to send a byte array, you should send the length first, so you know how many bytes to expect.